Many-to-Many Queries in Preset.io/Superset
I'm using Preset.io, but I believe the functionality is pretty much the same for Superset and PowerBI. I think it's more of a data question.
Imagine the following schema:
People



id
name
runtime_1
runtime_2
runtime_3
ridetime_1
ridetime_2
ridetime_3




1
John
12:00
12:31
12:23
28:03
28:16
27:56


2
Jane
null
null
null
24:34
25:15
25:10


3
Jim
null
null
null
null
null
null



Interests



id
interest




1
Biking


2
Running



People_Interests



people_id
interest_id




1
1


1
2


2
2



My query looks like the below:
SELECT p.*,
       LEAST(runtime_1, runtime_2, runtime_3) as fastest_runtime,
       LEAST(ridetime_1, ridetime_2, ridetime3) as fastest_ridetime,
       i.interest
FROM people AS p
LEFT JOIN people_interests AS pi ON p.id = pi.people_id
LEFT JOIN interests_i AS i ON pi.interests_id = i.id

This of course, returns the following results:
NOTE: I know LEAST won't return the results like this, but this is more psuedocode to show example results.



id
name
runtime_1
runtime_2
runtime_3
ridetime_1
ridetime_2
ridetime_3
fastest_runtime
fastest_ridetime
interest




1
John
12:00
12:31
12:23
28:03
28:16
27:56
12:00
27:56
Biking


1
John
12:00
12:31
12:23
28:03
28:16
27:56
12:00
27:56
Running


2
Jane
null
null
null
24:34
25:15
25:10
null
24:34
Running


3
Jim
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null



In Preset.io I need to do a few things:

I need to use filters for interest so the results must include them
I need to return AVG for fastest_runtime and fastest_ridetime for all people

The problem is that John is returning twice (because he has two interests). Therefore, The averages will be off. If it was a 1:M relationship, I wouldn't have a problem, but the M:M is presenting the problem.
How do I fix this?
